# Векторизатор на JS или PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, canvas

Знает ли кто, есть ли какой-то векторизатор растового изображения на JavaScript и/или PHP?

Изначально изображение рисуется в `canvas`, потом его нужно экспортировать в PNG/SVG...

С PNG проблем не возникло, а от с SVG - еще как)
Пример готовой реализации есть [здесь](https://pattern.flaticon.com/),  но **как** они это сделали - не могу понять?

Рисование в `canvas` реализовано с помощью библиотеки jCanvas.

Comment: Тогда это будет просто растеризатор (вектор в пиксели)
 (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), а для этого у большинства canvas есть механизм, благо там уже все нарисовано и остается сохранить. Ну а для этого можно использовать встроенные в Javascript функции или https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , Но эта библиотека НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТ сохранение canvas в svg формате

Comment: Боюсь, что задача в чистом виде не решаема: вектор легко сводится к растру, но обратно почти нереально. А `canvas` как раз таки рисует всё в растре. Самым нормальным решением будет сохранение всех произведённых команд и генерация их эквивалентов для `SVG` – функции для всяких линий, фигур, текстов, картинок и преобразований должны быть похожие. Возможно для этого существуют готовые библиотеки, но сомневаюсь, задача не из популярных.

Comment: Для сохранения canvas в SVG есть paper.js, уверен что есть и остальные библиотеки аналогичные ему.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov  да, я уже нашел нужную мне библиотеку canvas2svg благодаря Вам, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

[Сanvas2svg](https://github.com/gliffy/canvas2svg) - эта библиотека поможет превратить ваш Canvas в SVG с помощью javascript. Она позволяет вам создавать документ SVG с помощью canvas api.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере - на конструкторе Flaticon в  PNG конвертируется через Canvas. А в SVG собирается из исходников. То есть берет оригинал SVG, задает размер, позицию, поворот.
Соберите случайную картинку и изучите SVG-код, поищите закономерности.

Правда, в целях економии они один раз вставили картинку, а потом используют ее через [<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/use)